# Type '_Control' is not defined

Tags: vb.net

I created a function to check if there is a control type in my form or not, but It didn't worked and I don't know where is the problem.

This is the code I wrote:

```
Private Function testIfControlExists(ByVal _Control As Control)
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is _Control Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

This is the error message I get:

> Error 1   Type '_Control' is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the Form has the control type then you can do this:

```
Public Function testIfControlExists(ByVal _Control As Control) As Boolean
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If c.GetType Is _Control.GetType Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
If TypeOf c Is _Control Then
```

To

```
If TypeOf c Is Control Then
```

good luck

Comment: But this will test if the c is a Control and I want to test c if it's a type which I give as an argument in my function

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VB.TYPEOF%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

You cannot use it in the way you are attempting. You would use it against a data type name, such as `Integer`,`String` etc.